# WebRTC Session on Localhost

Tags: javascript, xampp, webrtc

Using the PeerConnection Demo 1 Here: https://webrtc-demos.appspot.com/html/pc1.html  Would there be support to run this over an XAMPP sever on Localhost and being able to connect two PC's together? It looks like there would be support, but I cannot get it to work. Any Javascript/HTML experts know what I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

The demo you linked only works in my Chrome Canary.

Try using this: http://simpl.info/peerconnection/ and https://apprtc.appspot.com.

Adapter.js (used in the apprtc link) enables cross-browser usage, and easy transition when prefixes are removed from the apis - very easy to implement.

I have both running on a local MAMPP server and only the latter needed some edits to get local video working. exchanging session descriptions for my local apprtc implementation is something i hope to have done very soon!

Comment: done!
https://apprtc.appspot.com is running via my Node.js signalling server. Let me know if you want my code.

Comment: I would love to see the code for your signaling server.  Is there a way we can make this happen?